# Unordered list and dynamic bullet images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my problem:

I have a unordered list that generates some items. I know that I can change the bullet to an image by using `list-style-image: url();`.

I want to be able to dynamically add a pre-existing image for each list item, let's say based on the list item `id`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: You want to _generate_ an image or you want to assign a _pre-existing_ image?

Comment: Add a pre existing image. So say there's a list item with an id of "Germany", the script should change the list style image for that list item to a pre existing image with the same name as the id. Hope that makes sense

Comment: So to further understand, you want to use different bullet images? So if you have a list item with the ID of Germany, it would show, theoretically, a German flag? Same with France, and Canada, and the USA?
 Theoretical images, just trying to understand what you want

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what I need if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a data attribute rather than an ID and assign a background image rather than using bullet points as you will have more control over the display of the images...

```js
$('.countries li').each(function() {
    var url = "http://www.sciencekids.co.nz/images/pictures/flags96/"
    var country = $(this).data('country');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + url + country + '.jpg)');
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-position: 0 center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="countries">
    <li data-country="United_Kingdom">UK</li>
    <li data-country="Germany">Germany</li>
    <li data-country="France">France</li>
    <li data-country="Spain">Spain</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This got me a solution in the end. It's not exactly the same but you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some valuable feedback from uʍopǝpısdu, this is what I have in the end and it works:

```
$("#list1").append('<li class="list-group-item" id=' + country.name + '><span class="badge">' + country.points + '</span>'  + ' '  + country.name +' </li>' ); 
$("#" + country.name).css('background-image', 'url(../img/flags/squareflags/' + country.name + '.png)');
```

Thanks!